# How can i set background-image for input tag?

Tags: css

I have this code atm:

```
<form id="" class="cf" action="">
        <div class="input_wrap cf">
            <label for="test"></label>
            <input id="test" type="text">
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here is css code :

```
    .test {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        background: url("../img/magnifying_glass_icon.svg") no-repeat right;
}
```

Where can be problem?
Tried lot of variants
Thanks

Comment: Change .test to #test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#test 
{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: url("../img/magnifying_glass_icon.svg") no-repeat scroll center right;
}
```

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream  since you didn't set **class** attribute for input type, you can use **id** for applying css. if you set class attribute as **test** your css would be working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.test {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        background: url("../img/magnifying_glass_icon.svg") no-repeat scroll center right;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exacly?

Comment: I've got it working here, you weren't targeting the element..http://codepen.io/eddyerburgh/pen/GozoBr

Comment: Problem was with id, not with class